# open a command prompt and setting the default path

Tags: command-line, batch-file

I want a `.bat` file which opens a command prompt and then set my default directory also set the enviromenet variable `JAVA_HOME`

For now I am manually openning command prompt and then setting my project directry path and then setting the environment variable.

I am using commands as :

```
open cmd.exe
cd d:\Code
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Jdk.1.6
```

I want that when I execute the batch file that execute the commant before openning. How to do that ?

Comment: there is no `open` command in cmd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want *specifically* a batch file to be clickable directly on Windows desktop, a simple, yet not elegant way, would be to use the following code in batch file:

```
@cd d:\Code
@set JAVA_HOME=C:\Jdk.1.6"
@cmd.exe /K
```

It will set the path and the variable, and in that context launch a nested command session with `/K` parameter - which will force it to wait for user input (instead of disappearing).

**A more elegant solution** would be to create a new shortcut on the desktop and configure it as follows:

- Command: `cmd /K set JAVA_HOME=C:\Jdk.1.6`
- Start in: `d:\Code`

Answer (score 1):

Try this batch script:

```
@echo off
set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Jdk.1.6"
cd /d "d:\Code"
cmd /k
```

Comment: +1 as it helped in understanding /d for directory which is what i was searching for. Thanks